# HttpServletRequest is null although I'm implementing ServletRequestAware

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2, httprequest

I have a form in JSP having two fields, and in action class I have an instance variable for each field, but those attributes are null when action class is executing.

I have used `validate()` method that is not even executing.

**JSP**

```xml
<s:form action="addAuthority">
    <table>
        <caption> <b><big>Add New Authority</big></b>

        </caption>
        <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
            <tr>
                <td><s:actionerror />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </s:if>
        <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
            <tr>
                <td><s:actionmessage />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </s:if>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <s:textfield name="role" label="Authority Name"></s:textfield </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <s:select name="dependentAuthority" list="#request.authorityList" label="Dependent Authority" listKey="roleId" listValue="role"></s:select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <s:submit value="Add"></s:submit>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

**Action**

```
public class AddAuthorityAction extends ActionSupport {
private String dependentAuthority;
private String role;
private Map<String, Object>  session;
private HttpServletRequest request;
public String execute() throws Exception{
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    //System.out.print(role + "  " + dependentAuthority+"  ");

    role = request.getParameter("role");
    dependentAuthority = request.getParameter("dependentAuthority");
    //System.out.print(role+"  "+ dependentAuthority);

    //insert the data
    int count = new DBInsert().addRoleDependency(role, Integer.parseInt(dependentAuthority));
    if(count==0){
        addActionError("There is some error while inserting. Please try again");
    }else{
        addActionMessage("Information successfully inserted");
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String moveAddAuthority() {
    Map request = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().get("request");

    List<Role> authorityList = new DBSelect().getAuthorityId();
    request.put("authorityList", authorityList);

    List<Role> roleWithDependency = new DBSelect().getRoleWithDependence();
    request.put("roleWithDependency", roleWithDependency);
    return SUCCESS;
}

public void validate() {
    if (role == null || role.trim().equals("")) {
        addFieldError("role", "The name is required");
    }
}   
public String getDependentAuthority() {
    return dependentAuthority;
}
public void setDependentAuthority(String dependentAuthority) {
    this.dependentAuthority = dependentAuthority;
}
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}}
```

1. when I am using `HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();` I can get the value;
2. but through implementing ServletRequestAware request become null;
3. without using both instance variable is null;
4. I could not get ActionMessage in JSP page.

**struts.xml**

```xml
<action name="addAuthority" class="nodue.action.AddAuthorityAction" 
      method="execute" >
        <interceptor-ref name="authonticateInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="redirect">moveAddAuthority</result>
    </action>
    <action name="moveAddAuthority" class="nodue.action.AddAuthorityAction" 
         method="moveAddAuthority">
        <interceptor-ref name="authonticateInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">/authority.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

I have made some modification on datatype of `dependentAuthority` previously it was Integer, and also added in JSP page the `<s:if>` tag.

Comment: I hope the getters and setters are public and have proper naming. Can you please also post the code for the same

Comment: I have added the full Action class and also given related modified JSP tags. added another problem the "could not get ActionMessage in JSP page"

Comment: Don't use request to get variables. Probably issue is in your interceptor stack, show it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are probably using a single Interceptor, while [you should use an entire stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24260452/1654265) with your interceptor in it.
2. You are returning the `redirect` result that should be used to reach  external URLs or non-action URLs. To redirect to an action [you should use `redirectAction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24180106/1654265) result.
3. No matter if `redirect` or `redirectAction`, when you redirect you lose the request parameters, and this is why you don't see action errors and messages. [There are different solutions to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186149/1654265).
4. You use the `validate()` method, that returns INPUT result when things go south. But you haven't defined any INPUT result for your actions; **be sure to understand [how the INPUT result works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265)**, along with `ValidationInterceptor` and `ParameterInterceptor`.

Comment: @AleksandrM I've used spinal-case ?! Ok, it's friday :D

Comment: I have a log-in page which is working with same structure. then why not in other cases